# CSS3 HTML5 Layer

Tags: html, css

I'm doing my Website but I have a problem. I have one background image and in this image, different layers:
layer are  with exactly the same size and same position. I tried this :

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div id="1">
   </div>
   <div id="2">
   </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #feecc5;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: absolue;
    background-image: url(images/fond.png);
    width: 600px;
    height: 960px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#1 {
    background-image: url(images/formation.png);
    width: 600px;
    height: 960px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#2 {
    background-image: url(images/experiences.png);
    width: 600px;
    height: 960px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

The background image for the body is perfect, after the different layers are very bad... I don t understand after i tried also a position: center for the div, nothing. Also put all the div "layer" in the general div, it doesn't work too. I don t know that i have to do. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please create an fiddle. (jsfiddle.com)

Comment: change your `IDs` to something other than numbers, like `#one` and `#two`

Answer (score 5):

In CSS, identifiers cannot start with a digit. This is why your styling isn't being applied.

**CSS2.1**

> [**Syntax and basic data types / 4.1.3 Characters and case**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)
>
> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

**CSS3**

> [**Syntax and basic data types / 4.1.3 Characters and case**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#characters)
>
> In CSS3, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors (see [SELECT] [or is this still true])) can contain only the characters [A-Za-z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters 161 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit** or a hyphen followed by a digit. They can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F". (See [UNICODE310] and [ISO10646].)

---

This obviously won't work [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/BNfea/):

```
#1 {
    color:red;
}
```

---

It would clearly work if you prepend a letter and changed the markup [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/KNH4C/)

```
#p1 {
    color:red;
}
```

---

As a work-around, you could use the attribute selector in order to select an `id` beginning with a number: [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/QaQh6/)

```
[id="1"] {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: So simple yet so..simple

Comment: Note this only applies to CSS, in HTML5, id's beginning with numbers are now valid.

Comment: OOO yes thanks a lot. But the problem still the same after i changed the id. The picture of the div one and two are not in the same position.